# Elves, dwarves and humans. Does anyone heal faster?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In LOTR *(and also in the Warhammer fantasy universe)* elves are immortal while dwarves have very long life spans.

Do elves heal faster than dwarves and do dwarves in turn heal faster than humans?

In LOTR canon, are there any examples of the healing time of the different species being noticeably different?

There may be examples of especially powerful individuals from the different species who heal quicker than regular beings, but I'd be most interested in the comparative healing time of the regular beings.

Comment: Hobbits heal the fastest! :)

Comment: Wolverine heals the fastest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Elves in Middle-earth the answer is in the essay entitled *Of Death and the Severance of Fea and Hroa* published in History of Middle-earth 10.  In this essay the word *Fea* (plural *Fear*) is Elvish for "spirit", and I have replaced the Elvish original with the English translation to avoid confusion here:

> Their spirits were tenacious therefore of life 'in the raiment of Arda', and far excelled the spirits of Men in power over that 'raiment', even from the first days protecting their bodies from many ills and assaults (such as disease), and **healing them swiftly of injuries, so that they recovered from wounds that would have proved fatal to Men**.

Elves therefore can endure greater wounds and heal from them faster than Men.

The Silmarillion chapter *Of Aule and Yavanna* has this to say about Dwarves:

> Therefore they are stone-hard, stubborn, fast in friendship and in enmity, and **they suffer toil and hunger and hurt of body more hardily than all other speaking peoples**...

This establishes Dwarvish endurance, but having reviewed *Of Dwarves and Men*, *Of Aule and Yavanna*, *Of the Sindar*, the Dwarf material in History of Middle-earth 11 and *Durin's Folk* in Appendix A, there is nothing I am aware of that establishes how fast they heal.

If we assume that greater endurance also means faster healing, and since Elves are included in "other speaking peoples" the ranking is therefore:

1. Dwarves
2. Elves
3. Men

I'm not aware how this compares to the Warhammer universe.

Comment: Great answer, very well researched!!

Comment: "Suffering hurt of body more hardily" doesn't necessarily mean "healing faster"; it could just mean "recovering from worse injury without dying", or even just "complaining less about things that hurt."

Comment: Totally agree with @MattGutting here. I would interpret this as "they don't feel pain as intense as other speaking peoples", not pertaining to their ability to heal. It seems only safe to say that Elves do heal faster than humans and Dwarves can endure pain better than both humans and elves.

Comment: Haha, just to note how being non-native english affected my read on this answer- "they suffer toil and hunger and hurt of body more hardily than all other speaking peoples"- I read as meaning that Dwarves being more easily hurt or hungry than any other speaking race. The fault for me was "hardily", as the translation in my mind took it too - rougher, more severe or intense. It's good to learn something new everyday! :D

Comment: @Dagon313 especially seeing Gimli's attitude toward pain and suffering. I think that points much more towards my interpretation.

Comment: So Dwarves have the most HP, but Elves have a higher REGEN stat.

Comment: @MattGutting - I'm inclined to agree; I can't at present source anything relating to Dwarves' healing rate.

Comment: In light of Matt's revelation, I think I may have accepted this answer prematurely. I'm going to un-tick it for the time being to see if anyone else can suggest something else. I'll mark this as right again if no one can come up with anything better because it's still a very good answer!

Comment: "Pain don't hurt" - Dwarves

Comment: @Daft - that's fair, yes.  I'm going to see if I can source a reference for Dwarvish healing too; I haven't been able to so far, so it may be the case that there just isn't one.

Comment: @Daft - I've reviewed all of the Dwarf material but haven't located anything indicating how fast they heal; question updated to reflect this.  Unless there's a passing mention in narrative, this is probably information that just doesn't exist.